# Activist vs. Activism

Tags: modifiers

What is the difference between "activist" and "activism" when they are used as modifiers? What is correct - "activist project" or "activism project"?

Comment: What's the intended usage? An "activist project" is a project about activists, an "activism project" is a project about activism.

Comment: The first might be an activist's project, the second a project on activism.

Comment: I mean, a project I do as an activist, a project I see as a part of my activities as an activist.